# angular material suggest md- tags with Visual studio comunity edition 2015

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, material-design, angular-material

Does anyone know how to setup visual studio to suggest `"md-"` tags? When I start typing

```
 <md-t..
```

toolbar, tooltip is suggested and the tag auto closes

Comment: Are you referring to bootstrap classes?  You need to be sure you PM> Install-Package bootstrap -Version 3.3.5 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/.  Do not use alpha as this is still not a full-blown version yet.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material latest version not supporting IntelliSense.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngularJS.Intellisense/

Only AngularJS Core with Materials (ver >= 1.3.0 && <1.4.0) have intelliSence

Not too many tags in Angular Material so you can reference on the API page.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

Basically and technically, VS2015 will autocomplete you HTML tag when you use ">" close tag

Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949818/6716449

### Update

you ca switch to Atom, which provides packages for Angular. in your case you may wanna use https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-angular-material